# Chinese-characters learning software for Ubuntu (Linux)

Tags: mandarin, characters, simplified-characters, learning, software

I am looking for a software that shows a Chinese alphabet/word on my desktop with its pinyin and meaning in English, and each day it will give a different word.

Since I am using a Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) system, I didn't find lot of choices to learn Mandarin on this OS, at the contrary for Windows and Android. The best software that I know and use until now is [**ZDT** (Zhongwen Development Tool)](http://zdt.sourceforge.net/), however it doesn't have a desktop memorizing-gadget that I search.

Thank you

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but Anki is far superior to ZDT, which hasn't been updated for five years. I'm not aware of any plugin that does the desktop integration you want for Anki, which is why this is not an answer to your question, just a suggestion if you can't find anything and consider using ZDT. It makes me a bit nostalgic, though, since I started learning Chinese with ZDT more than 13 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

https://zd.321yy.com/zi/zuichangyongzi/

I find a website for you. Maybe this is not what you asked but it can help you learn the most common used hanzi(chinese character) with pinyin.

Comment: thank you for this website

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **Paley** is a choice
[image]

But I don't think the software works very well

Comment: Xiéxié @Han Bingjin. Do you have a link to download it please ?

Comment: you just need to type in  “sudo apt install parley”  And you can find more infomation on “https://apps.kde.org/en/parley”

Comment: Xiéxié @Han Bingjin

Comment: Xiéxié? It was supposed to be Xièxiè if you wanted to say "thanks".